# Getting Maximum Recursion Error when trying to override QTreeView.edit()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview

The title says most of it. I have to be something dumb here but for some reason anytime I try to override the edit function of a QTreeView when I right click on the Treeview I get a Maximum recursion depth error.

This is specifically when I try to call the super's edit function. Here is an example of the problem. What am I messing up here?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class EditTreeView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):

    editingRequested = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QModelIndex)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(EditTreeView, self).__init__(parent)

    def edit(self, index, QAbstractItemView_EditTrigger=None, QEvent=None):
        super(EditTreeView, self).edit(index)


class testTreeview(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(testTreeview, self).__init__(parent)
        self.mainTree = EditTreeView()
        self.lo = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.lo.addWidget(self.mainTree)
        self.setLayout(self.lo)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.mainTree.setModel(self.model)

    def populate(self):
        row = [QtGui.QStandardItem('teststuff'), ]
        root = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
        root.appendRow(row)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    volume = testTreeview()
    volume.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation:

QTreeView inherits from QAbstractItemView, and if you review the methods of that class, you can see that there are 2 methods with the same name:

> #### bool QAbstractItemView::edit(const QModelIndex &index,
>   QAbstractItemView::EditTrigger trigger, QEvent *event)
>
> Starts editing the item at index, creating an editor if necessary, and
>   returns true if the view's State is now EditingState; otherwise
>   returns false.
>
> The action that caused the editing process is described by trigger,
>   and the associated event is specified by event.
>
> Editing can be forced by specifying the trigger to be
>   QAbstractItemView::AllEditTriggers.

---

> #### void QAbstractItemView::edit(const QModelIndex &index)
>
> Starts editing the item corresponding to the given index if it is
>   editable.
>
> Note that this function does not change the current index. Since the
>   current index defines the next and previous items to edit, users may
>   find that keyboard navigation does not work as expected. To provide
>   consistent navigation behavior, call setCurrentIndex() before this
>   function with the same model index.

It is observed that the first method is more general than the second one, so it gives us a suspicion that the second one will use the first one and indeed this happens if [the source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp?h=5.13#n1198) is reviewed:

```
void QAbstractItemView::edit(const QModelIndex & index)
{
    Q_D(QAbstractItemView);
    if (Q_UNLIKELY(!d->isIndexIsValid(index)))
        qWarning("edit: index was invalid");
    if (Q_UNLIKELY(!edit(index, AllEditTriggers, 0)))
        qWarning("edit: editing failed");
}
```

So in your case clearly explain the error: you are overriding the first method and invoking the second, but the second uses the first according to the source code, and returned to the infinite cycle.

---

## Solution

The solution is to use the super of the same method with all the parameters:

```
class EditTreeView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    editingRequested = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QModelIndex)

    def edit(self, index, trigger, event):
        self.editingRequested.emit(index)
        return super(EditTreeView, self).edit(index, trigger, event)
```

But keep in mind that the override is about the first method, in C++ it is allowed to have methods with the same name but in python if there are several methods with the same name the last one will erase the previous ones.

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems you are solving all my problems recently.